# What does cmake do with Unnecessary links

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm cleaning/refactoring a quite old project and I realized they made the mistake(?) of adding unnecessary links to the targets in all the CMakeLists.txt files:

```
LIST(APPEND ${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBRARIES RecursiveLy_generated_list_with_unnecessarystuff)
target_link_libraries(sample PUBLIC ${${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBRARIES})
```

I replaced the list by one that contains only the necessary links and the compilation time got noticeably reduced.

1. So I'm wondering what does `cmake` do when the symbols of a library that was linked are not used?
2. I also cleaned the include directories (ALL the .h files of the project were recursively added (many not needed)), did `cmake` think the symbols were used because they appeared in the headers even if this headers were not `#include`d ?

Comment: cmake doesn't know what is used or not. It just honers dependency definition provided in `target_link_libraries`. Depending on linked targets linker can drop unused stuff.

Comment: @MarekR for static and object libraries, see [the `OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES.html)

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587). Please also provide more detail about these libraries. Are they static or shared/dynamic?

Comment: @user: According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES.html) the property `OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES` may remove only a link to a library with **another language**. E.g. it never removes a link between static C libraries .

Comment: @user I think I improved the title. You think it changes too much  for static/dynamic/shared... libs? In my case they are dynamic, but I thought that was not necessary info in the question.

Comment: @MarekR `OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES` doesn't seem to check if the symbols "are used"

Comment: @Ivan I didn't wrote about that :). Note documentation says it applies only for static libraries and object files (not sure on which side it applies: target/dependency).

Comment: You thought it was Marek who wrote that, but it was me! Dio!

Comment: IMO you should trash this `${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBRARIES` and clean up dependencies. Someone though this is handy, but here did terrible thing. There is big chance of dependency cycle. Just clean this up and list required dependencies manually for each target. It should be quite easy (it will take just some time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does cmake do with Unnecessary links

Passes proper command line options to the compiler.

> what does cmake do when the symbols of a library that was linked are not used?

Nothing. CMake is not even aware that symbols of a library are or are not used. CMake does not link your code, compiler does.

> did cmake think the symbols were used because they appeared in the headers even if this headers were not #included ?

No, CMake is unaware of what symbols are used where. CMake is unaware of the content of header files. CMake creates a list of commands to run. What commands to run depends on what is written in CMakeLists.txt.